# new activity won't start after clicked navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I am aware that this question exists but the answers don't work for my case.
I have a navigation drawer with four items, but when I click on the first one (the one i'm working on right now), the new activity I created doesn't open, I have looked and tried everything I found on the internet but nothing seems to work.
i'm kinda new to android studio so I really don't know how to fix this. The android studio version I am using is 3.0.
This is my menu xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Icons made by http://www.freepik.com
from "https://www.flaticon.com
is licensed by http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/-->
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/m1" android:title="Agora Mall"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_ammunition"/>
<item android:id="@+id/m2" android:title="Downtown Center"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_ammunition"/>
<item android:id="@+id/m3" android:title="Galeria 360"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_ammunition"/>
<item android:id="@+id/m4" android:title="Sambil"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_ammunition"/>
</menu>
```

this is the main activity class code:

```
package com.example.arlet.storemaps;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open,  R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.m1:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AgoraActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must implement `onNavigationItemSelected()` for the navigation drawer menu.  
`onOptionsItemSelected()` is related to the toolbar options menu items.  
You can find all the necessary code for this if you create a new project and choose

> Navigation Drawer Activity

as the type of your MainActivity.

Comment: i really don't know, i'm sorry if i did, i'm still a noob in this website @mTak, i just don't want to start a new project, but i guess i'll have to, thanks for taking your time to answer my question.

Comment: @Ichigo well you did and I don't understand why

Comment: i'm sorry, it was a mistake

Comment: @Ichigo will you acept it again?

Comment: okay, in the end you were right, I have to recreate the main activity, sorry for bothering and thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

You Can handle navigation drawer item click in following way:

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                case R.id.m1:
                    Intent intent = new  Intent(MainActivity.this, AgoraActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                    break;
                case R.id.m2:

                    break;
                case R.id.m3:

                    break;
                case R.id.m4:

                    break;

            }


            menuItem.setChecked(true);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: hi, so i tried what you said, in combination with what @Bosco answered and now an error appears indicating that a method call is expected:

Comment: thanks for the interest, but I am going to recreate the avtivity, thanks again for all the help

Answer (score 0):

You must implement NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener for the drawer items to work perfectly

Add this to your class declaration

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
// then overide this method to
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {        
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch(id){
            case R.id.m1:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AgoraActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            //other cases goes here
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    //you might want to ovewrite this method too
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry for bothering, but what is this method for? I understand the previous one but this one not so much, and thank you for taking your time to answer my question @Bosco.

Comment: onBackPressed is an event triggered when the android back button is pressed and the if statement checks if the drawer is open and closes it else it perform the back button action on the activity stack

Comment: also, when i added the implements part an error was appearing, it requires me to add some new methods.

Comment: if you are using android studio, recreate the activity and choose Navigation Drawer Activity, it will generate everything for you

Comment: yeah, that's what I am going to do, thanks for the interest